# Script conflict Mootools Validation with jQuery Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mootools

Ok guys, I have the following problem I have a script to slideToggle obtained from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle) site, and [another](http://web-kreation.com/all/lightform-free-ajaxphp-contact-form/) called formcheck.js form validation, I only load one at a time, I can avoid this conflict as I tried $.noConflict(true) without success helps the code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lang/es.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/formcheck.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ check = new FormCheck('third', {
        display : {
            fadeDuration : 500,
            errorsLocation : 1,
            indicateErrors : 1,
            showErrors : 1
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip4").click(function(){
        $("#panel4").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip5").click(function(){
        $("#panel5").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the jQuery part:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#flip4").click(function () {
        jQuery("#panel4").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    jQuery("#flip5").click(function () {
        jQuery("#panel5").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    jQuery("#flip").click(function () {
        jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**Or do it all with Mootools:**

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    check = new FormCheck('third', {
        display: {
            fadeDuration: 500,
            errorsLocation: 1,
            indicateErrors: 1,
            showErrors: 1
        }
    });
    document.id("flip4").addEvent('click', function () {
        document.id("panel4").toggle();
    });
    document.id("flip5").addEvent('click', function () {
       document.id("panel5").toggle();
    });
    document.id("flip").addEvent('click', function () {
        document.id("panel").toggle();
    });
});
```

If you go for Mootools effects you can use [reveal()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Element%3areveal) and [dissolve()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Element%3adissolve) to hide/show also.